# My django blogging apps facebook share buttonposts wrong images

Tags: django, facebook, heroku

I currently have a blogging app hosted on heroku with a facebook share button. I googled read some post hear and other sites and came to the conclusion that I'm supposed to use meta tags in my head. So after running my url through the facebook url debugger and seeing these results

```
Inferred Property The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
    Inferred Property The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
    Inferred Property The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
    Inferred Property The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
    Share App ID Missing The 'fb:app_id' property should be explicitly provided, Specify the app ID so that stories shared to Facebook will be properly attributed to the app. Alternatively, app_id can be set in url when open the share dialog.
```

I did this

```
{% block fb_meta %}
     <!- Search for these meta tags -->
        <meta property="og:title" content="{{ post.title }}" />
        <meta property="og:image" content="{{ post.image_url }}" />
        <meta property="og:description" content="{{post.body}}">
        <meta property="og:site_name" content="ysite"/>
        <meta property="og:url" content="http:mysitedotcom{{ post.get_absolute_url }}" />
        <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
        <meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
        <!-- Author info -->
        <meta property="article:author" content="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100013675372228" />
        <meta property="article:publisher" content="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100013675372228" />
        <!-- End -->
    {% endblock fb_meta %}
```

on my detail page and this in my head

```
{% block fb_meta %}
{% endblock fb_meta %}
```

It still does not work and shows the wrong pic, even after I deleted it. And when I check my console everything shows in the tags

like this

[image]

What is my issue? thanks for all help

EDIT this is the out put when I enter a url at facebook debugger

[image]

another question does order matter?

Comment: What is the URL to the page?

Comment: it's in the image above where it says og:url.

Answer (score 1):

the following has been working for me. I have been fetching new scrape information which has the effect of updating the pic and for others who mayneed this info in the future the following is from the face book docs

1. Pre-cache the image with the URL Debugger
   Run the URL through the URL debugger to pre-fetch metadata for the page. You should also do this if you update the image for a piece of content.
2. Use og:image:width and og:image:height Open Graph tags
   Using these tags will specify the image to the crawler so that it can render it immediately without having to asynchronously.